# Giving a user permission to the /home directory

Tags: linux, permissions, user-accounts, centos

I am using CentOS 5.x. I would like to give a user permission to write on the /home directory. Do I have to make it a sudoer? Or is there any other better way for that?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain a little bit more why the user needs to access the /home directory, it is not usual and can be a serious security risk.

Comment: @jhcaiced +1. To share data safely between users, make sure they belong to a common group and grant permissions to this group, to write to the shared directory owned by that group.

Comment: A bit more info - if you give them permission to add to this dir, they can delete from this dir too, meaning they can wipe out *every* user here, not something that is suggested

Comment: well...its like i want this user to be a domain manager, who can access all the domains and edit it from a website, kind of a whm thing, just my own.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advised to give a user besides root access to the whole /home dir. Ask yourself if it's necessary to have access to /home.

You can:

1. make the user a member of the group set on /home (default is root)
2. give everyone access to /home with `chmod` (most certainly not advised!)